# Storing and using type information in C

Tags: c, casting, null-pointer

I'm coming from Java and I'm trying to implement a doubly linked list in C as an exercise. I wanted to do something like the Java generics where I would pass a pointer type to the list initialization and this pointer type would be use to cast the list void pointer but I'm not sure if this is possible?

What I'm looking for is something that can be stored in a list struct and used to cast *data to the correct type from a node. I was thinking of using a double pointer but then I'd need to declare that as a void pointer and I'd have the same problem.

```
typedef struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
} node;

typedef struct list {
    node *head;
    node *tail;
   //??? is there any way to store the data type of *data? 
} list;
```

Comment: I don't understand all this stuff about *null pointers* ... `0` evaluates to a null pointer of any type, as does `(void *)0` ... but as for the clearer question in the comment of your code: Not really, you have to come up with an own solution (like e.g. an `enum` for types you use). Type information in C isn't there any more once compiled, so there's no object of type "type".

Comment: Could use `void list_put_int(list *L, int *p) { .... xx.data = p; ...}` and `int *list_get_int(list *L) {   .... return xx.data;}`  yet as [@Felix Palmen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684292/storing-and-casting-null-pointer-type-in-c#comment76352825_44684292) said, there's no object of type "type" and no cast that changes at run-time, (aside from maybe VLAs.and that would not help here anyways.)

Comment: Code _could_ use `_Generic` with a macro to achieve most of the goal.  Tis a bit convoluted.

Comment: @FelixPalmen You're right, sorry my brain dropped in null instead of void, updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the use of specific functions like the following are used.

```
void    List_Put_int(list *L, int *i);
void    List_Put_double(list *L, double *d);
int *   List_Get_int(list *L);
double *List_Get_double(list *L);
```

---

A not so easy for learner approach uses `_Generic`. C11 offers `_Generic` which allows for code, at compile time, to be steered as desired based on type.

The below offers basic code to save/fetch to 3 types of pointers.  The macros would need expansion for each new types.  `_Generic` does not allow 2 types listed that may be the same like  `unsigned *` and `size_t *`.  So there are are limitations.

The `type_id(X)` macros creates an enumeration for the 3 types which may be use to check for run-time problems as with `LIST_POP(L, &d);` below.

```
typedef struct node {
  void *data;
  int type;
} node;

typedef struct list {
  node *head;
  node *tail;
} list;

node node_var;
void List_Push(list *l, void *p, int type) {
  // tbd code - simplistic use of global for illustration only
  node_var.data = p;
  node_var.type = type;
}

void *List_Pop(list *l, int type) {
  // tbd code
  assert(node_var.type == type);
  return node_var.data;
}

#define cast(X,ptr) _Generic((X), \
  double *: (double *) (ptr), \
  unsigned *: (unsigned *) (ptr), \
  int *: (int *) (ptr) \
  )

#define type_id(X) _Generic((X), \
  double *: 1, \
  unsigned *: 2, \
  int *: 3 \
  )

#define LIST_PUSH(L, data)  { List_Push((L),(data), type_id(data)); }
#define LIST_POP(L, dataptr) (*(dataptr)=cast(*dataptr, List_Pop((L), type_id(*dataptr))) )
```

Usage example and output

```
int main() {
  list *L = 0; // tbd initialization
  int i = 42;
  printf("%p %d\n", (void*) &i, i);
  LIST_PUSH(L, &i);
  int *j;
  LIST_POP(L, &j);
  printf("%p %d\n", (void*) j, *j);
  double *d;
  LIST_POP(L, &d);
}

42
42
assertion error
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want in C. There is no way to store a type in a variable and C doesn't have a template system like C++ that would allow you to fake it in the preprocessor.

You could define your own template-like macros that could quickly define your `node` and `list` structs for whatever type you need, but I think that sort of hackery is generally frowned upon unless you *really* need a whole bunch of linked lists that only differ in the type they store.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have any runtime type information and doesn't have a type "Type". Types are meaningless once the code was compiled. So, there's no solution to what you ask *provided by the language*.

One common reason you would want to have a type available at runtime is that you have some code that might see different instances of your container and must do different things for different types stored in the container. You can easily solve such a situation using an `enum`, e.g.

```
enum ElementType
{
    ET_INT; // int
    ET_DOUBLE; // double
    ET_CAR; // struct Car
    // ...
 };
```

and enumerate any type here that should ever go into your container. Another reason is if your container should take ownership of the objects stored in it and therefore must know how to destroy them (and sometimes how to clone them). For such cases, I recommend the use of function pointers:

```
typedef void (*ElementDeleter)(void *element);
typedef void *(*ElementCloner)(const void *element);
```

Then extend your struct to contain these:

```
typedef struct list {
    node *head;
    node *tail;
    ElementDeleter deleter;
    ElementCloner cloner;
} list;
```

Make sure they are set to a function that actually deletes resp. clones an element of the type to be stored in your container and then use them where needed, e.g. in a remove function, you could do something like

```
myList->deleter(myNode->data);
// delete the contained element without knowing its type
```

Answer (score 0):

create enum type, that will store data type and alloc memory according to this enum. This could be done in switch/case construction.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike Java or C++, C does not provide any type safety.  To answer your question succinctly, by rearranging your node type this way:

```
struct node {
   node* prev;  /* put these at front */
   node* next;
   /* no data here */
};
```

You could then separately declare nodes carrying any data

```
struct data_node {.
    data_node *prev;            // keep these two data members at the front 
    data_node *next;            // and in the same order as in struct list.

    // you can add more data members here.
};
/* OR... */
enter code here
struct data_node2 {
  node node_data;    /* WANING: this may look a bit safer, but is _only_ if placed at the front.
  /*  more data ... */
};
```

You can then create a library that operates on data-less lists of `node`s.

```
void list_add(list* l, node* n);
void list_remove(list* l, node* n);
/* etc... */
```

And by casting, use this 'generic lists' api to do operation on your list

You can have some sort of type information in your list declaration, for what it's worth, since C does not provide meaningful type protection.

```
struct data_list
{
  data_node* head;    /* this makes intent clear. */
  data_node* tail;
};

struct data2_list
{
  data_node2* head;
  data_node2* tail;
};

/* ... */

data_node* my_data_node = malloc(sizeof(data_node));
data_node2* my_data_node2 = malloc(sizeof(data_node2));

/* ... */

list_add((list*)&my_list, (node*)my_data_node); 
list_add((list*)&my_list2, &(my_data_node2->node_data)); 

/* warning above is because one could write this */
list_add((list*)&my_list2, (node*)my_data_node2); 


/* etc... */
```

These two techniques generate the same object code, so which one you choose is up to you, really.

As an aside, avoid the typedef struct notation if your compiler allows, most compilers do, these days.  It increases readability in the long run, IMHO. You can be certain some won't and some will agree with me on this subject though.

Comment: *C does not provide any type safety* -- you don't really mean that? Probably you mean you have to sacrifice some type safety for type-generic code or something along those lines.

Comment: @felixpalmen  some C compilers treat all data pointers as void*.

Comment: I wouldn't call such a thing a "C compiler". Do you have an example for this broken behavior, that would allow to implicitly convert any data pointer type to any other?

Comment: @FelixPalmen `A a; B* b; void* p = &a; b=p;`

Comment: `void *` is the *generic* pointer type. See my first comment. And in fact, what you outline here is very likely undefined behavior. What I don't see is a compiler "*treating all data pointers as void\**". All data pointers are implicitly convertible from/to `void *`, as per the standard.

Comment: If that was UB, every non-casted call to malloc() and free() would lead to undefined behaviour.  It could lead to UB if A and B are _binary incompatible_.  In any case, it demonstrates that C does not provide type safety.  Which is something someone coming from the Java world, as the OP states, should be aware of.

Comment: You're wrong. It leads to UB *as soon* as A and B aren't compatible types, and the rules for compatible types are quite narrow.

Comment: You're wrong.  Code similar to what I describe in my comment is widely used in the C world. If in doubt, have a close look at any posix socket implementation.

Comment: The POSIX socket API is the best example of widespread ill-defined C. Just because people use it doesn't make it correct. Sure, assigning your pointers as shown above isn't UB yet, *accessing* the object most certainly *is*: C11 §6.5.16.1 -- 3 "*If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way
the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall
have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined.*" -- still no relation to your false claim about type safety in C.

Comment: Keep in mind that the c89 standard was made so that sockets would still compile and you'll understand c.

Comment: There's no such thing as c98, you probably mean c89. Sockets code of course compiles, but you have to be *very* careful with aliasing pointers, you can *easily* invoke UB with this mess. And of course, code invoking UB compiles as well. *You* should try to "understand C", and your claim *C does not provide any type safety* is just plain wrong.